# Prioritize lookup-criterias and select latest value that fullfills the prioritized lookup-critiera

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
   |      A       |  
---|--------------|--
1  |    O.K.      |    
2  |    Warning   | 
3  |    Error     | 
4  |    Warning   | 
5  |    O.K.      |
6  |    Error     |
7  |    O.K.      |
8  |    O.K.      |
9  |    O.K.      |
10 |              |
11 |              |
---|--------------|---
12 |    Warning   |
13 |              |
```

---

In the `Range A1:A11` I want to

1. check if there is a value `<> O.K.`
2. If yes, the values with `Warning` should be prioritized over the values with `Error` and displayed accordingly in `cell A12`.

So far I am able to make the first step and figure out if there is a value `<> O.K.`

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((A1:A11<>"O.K.")*(A1:A11<>"")),A1:A11)
```

However, with this formula the result in `Cell A12` is `Error`. 
How do I have to modify it to prioritize `Warning` above `Error`?

Comment: But can there be entries other than "Error" or "Warning" that you would wish to be returned if neither of those two were present?

Comment: It will be only "Error" or "Warning"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ***Excel-365*** try-

```
=@SORT(FILTER(A1:A11,A1:A11<>"O.K."),,-1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no Error or Warning it should print O.K.

```
=XLOOKUP("Warning",A1:A9,A1:A9,XLOOKUP("Error",A1:A9,A1:A9,"O.K.",0,1),0,1)
```