# Exclude certain values from SORT function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
   |      A       |  
---|--------------|--
1  |    inactive  |    
2  |    Warning   | 
3  |    Error     | 
4  |    Warning   | 
5  |    O.K.      |
6  |    Error     |
7  |    O.K.      |
8  |    O.K.      |
9  |    inactive  |
10 |              |
11 |              |
---|--------------|---
12 |    Warning   |
13 |              |
```

---

In the `Range A1:A11` I want to

1. check if there is a value `<> O.K.`
2. If yes, the values with `Warning` should be prioritized over the values with `Error` and displayed accordingly in `cell A12`.
3. The value `inactive` - and any other value except `Error` and `Warning` - should be **completely ignored**.

With reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70243308/prioritize-lookup-criterias-and-select-latest-value-that-fullfills-the-prioritiz) I was able to make the first 2 bullet points work:

```
=@SORT(FILTER(A1:A11,A1:A11<>"O.K."),,-1)
```

However, with this formula the result in `Cell A12` is `inactive` but it should be `warning`. 
How do I have to modify it to completely ignore `inactive` and any other value except `Warning` and `Error`?

Comment: So what do you want to display when both 'Warning' or 'Error' are **not** present?

Comment: If there are only Errors A12 = "Error". If there are only Warnings A12 = "Warning". If there are both Errors and Warnings --> Prioritize Warnings over Error  A12 = "Warning". Inactive should be completely ignored.

Comment: I asked what you want to display when they both are **not** present.

Comment: Either A12 should be empty or it can be displayed "all inactive".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Microsoft365 dynamic formulas variant:

```
=@SORT(FILTER(A1:A11,(A1:A11="Warning")+(A1:A11="Error"),"O.K."),1,-1)
```

Comment: It works in the specific example. However, when all of them are "O.K." it displays nothing but it should display O.K. That was the only condition that we did not discuss yet in the comments.

Comment: When there are only O.K. and inactive in the range it should also display "O.K.'"

Comment: @Michi, are there any other possible values?

Comment: Nope. It will be only those 4.

Comment: Then the edit should work @Michi. But I'm not a 100% sure since you shown two empty cells too.